# passing object with value to another class java

Tags: java, object, authentication

I like to pass the information of an object from my GebruikerRepository class to ReservatieRepository class.

```
public class GebruikerRepository extends Observable {


List<Gebruiker> gebruikers;
Gebruiker aangemeldeGebruiker;
private Gebruiker huidigGebruiker;
private ObservableList<Gebruiker> oGebruikers;
private FilteredList<Gebruiker> filteredGebruikers;
DBCommunicatie databank = new DBCommunicatie();
private Email email;
```

So I like to initialise "email" after someone logged in succesfully
this happend in this methode:

```
 public void meldAan(String gebruikersnaam, String wachtwoord) {
        Gebruiker gebruiker = geefGebruiker(gebruikersnaam);
        gebruiker.controleerWachtwoord(wachtwoord);
        aangemeldeGebruiker = gebruiker;
        email= new Email();
        email.setEmailWachtwoord(wachtwoord);
        email.setVerzender(geefGebruiker(gebruikersnaam).getEmailadres());

    }
```

Now I want pass this email object to my ReservatieRepository

```
    public class ReservatieRepository extends Observable {

    private Reservatie geselecteerdeReservatie;
    private ObservableList<Reservatie> reservaties;
    private ObservableList<ReservatieSpecificatie> reservatieSpecs;
    private FilteredList<Reservatie> filteredReservaties;
    private Email emailadres;
    private GebruikerRepository gebruikerRepository;

    private DBCommunicatie databank = new DBCommunicatie();

    public ReservatieRepository() {

        reservaties = FXCollections.observableArrayList(haalReservatiesOp());
        reservatieSpecs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<>());
        filteredReservaties = new FilteredList<>(reservaties, p -> true);

    }
```

I would like to use the passed Email object with the initialised value after logged in GebruikerRepository in this methode.
Here I want set the third attribute of "Email".

```
 public void verwijderReservatie(Reservatie reservatie) {

    gebruikerRepository =new GebruikerRepository();
    emailadres = gebruikerRepository.geefEmail();
    emailadres.setReservatie(reservatie);
    emailadres.berichtVerwijderdReservatie();
```

I tried to make a GebruikerRepository object and try to use the getter to get that "Email" object. But somehow I always get a nullpointer here.

```
emailadres.setReservatie(reservatie);
```

Here is the attribute/constructor of my Email class.

```
public class Email {

private Reservatie reservatie;
private String ontvanger;
private String verzender;
private String emailWachtwoord ;


public Email(Reservatie reservatie,String verzender, String emailWachtwoord) {
    setReservatie(reservatie);
    setVerzender(verzender);
    setEmailWachtwoord(emailWachtwoord);
}

public Email(){

}
```

thx in advance!

Comment: By doing `gebruikerRepository = new GebruikerRepository();` you are creating a new object. You'll always get a `null` value when you do `gebruikerRepository.geefEmail();`.

Comment: Yea now it's clear thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`gebruikerRepository =new GebruikerRepository();` will always create an uninitialized GebruikerRepository-object, so any fields will be null (unless you set them via some `init()` - method.

You could try to get the Gebruiker corresponding with that Reservatie from the Reservatie itself, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) if you need to have only one email object active all the time for an instance of application.

Comment: hmm that's a good idea.is it allowed to have setters/getters in a singleton object?

Comment: Yes, you can have getter and setter in the singleton object. Basically, the idea of using it in such a way is composition. The output of SingletonComplexObject.java shows you that you can set the email object's attributes and print it. However, the object remains same (in memory).

You can try out below example.
https://github.com/MastersOfAlgoAndDS/DesignPatterns/blob/master/src/SingletonDesignPattern/Email.java
https://github.com/MastersOfAlgoAndDS/DesignPatterns/blob/master/src/SingletonDesignPattern/SingletonComplexObject.java